# asp.net sql or collection problem

Tags: asp.net, sql

following is the code on Placementsearch.aspx.cs

```
protected void Ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                int course_id = Convert.ToInt32(course.SelectedValue);
                int passoutYear = Convert.ToInt32(passout.SelectedValue);
                int currentBacklog = Convert.ToInt32(currrentBacklogDDL.SelectedValue);
                int sex = Convert.ToInt32(gender.SelectedValue);
                int? eGap = null;
                int? firstYrPercent = null;
                int? secondYrPercent = null;
                int? thirdYrPercent = null;
                int? finalYearpercent = null;
                int? currentDegeePercentage = null;
                int? highSchoolPercentge = null;
                int? higherSchoolPercentage = null;
                int? grauationPercentage = null;
                int? diplomaPercentage = null;
                int? noOfAtkt = null;
                DateTime? date = null;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DOB.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    string dateOfBirth = DOB.Text.Trim();
                    DateTime birthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfBirth, "dd/mm/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    string outPut = birthDate.ToString("mm/dd/YYYY");
                    date = Convert.ToDateTime(outPut);
                }                

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(educationGap.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    eGap = Convert.ToInt32(educationGap.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstYear.Text))
                {
                    firstYrPercent = Convert.ToInt32(firstYear.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondYear.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    secondYrPercent = Convert.ToInt32(secondYear.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thirdYear.Text))
                {
                    thirdYrPercent = Convert.ToInt32(thirdYear.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(finalyear.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    finalYearpercent = Convert.ToInt32(finalyear.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentDegree.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    currentDegeePercentage = Convert.ToInt32(currentDegree.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(higherSchool.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    higherSchoolPercentage = Convert.ToInt32(higherSchool.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(highSchool.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    highSchoolPercentge = Convert.ToInt32(highSchool.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(graduation.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    grauationPercentage = Convert.ToInt32(graduation.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(diploma.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    diplomaPercentage = Convert.ToInt32(diploma.Text.Trim());
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(atkt.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    noOfAtkt = Convert.ToInt32(atkt.Text.Trim());
                }

                Dictionary<string, object> paramList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                paramList.Add("@courseId", course_id);
                paramList.Add("@passoutYear", passoutYear);
                paramList.Add("@currentBacklog", currentBacklog);
                paramList.Add("@sex", sex);
                paramList.Add("@eGap", eGap);
                paramList.Add("@firstYrPercent", firstYrPercent);
                paramList.Add("@secondYrPercent", secondYrPercent);
                paramList.Add("@thirdYrPercent", thirdYrPercent);
                paramList.Add("@finalYearpercent", finalYearpercent);
                paramList.Add("@currentDegeePercentage", currentDegeePercentage);
                paramList.Add("@highSchoolPercentge", highSchoolPercentge);
                paramList.Add("@higherSchoolPercentage", higherSchoolPercentage);
                paramList.Add("@grauationPercentage",  grauationPercentage);
                paramList.Add("@diplomaPercentage", diplomaPercentage);
                paramList.Add("@noOfAtkt", noOfAtkt);
                paramList.Add("@date", date);
                StringBuilder branchId= new StringBuilder();
                foreach (ListItem li in branch.Items)
                {
                    if (li.Selected)
                    {
                        branchId.Append(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));
                    }
                }
                DataTable dt = searchManager.GetEligibleStudent(paramList, branchId);



            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            COMMON.logger.Error("Error On Button click Ok", ex);
        }
```

this is the method which is called from above page. this method is on class searchstudentDAO.cs

```
public DataTable GetEligibleStudent(Dictionary<string, object> paramList, StringBuilder branchId)
    {
        try
        {
            string cmd = @"SELECT * FROM [tbl_students] WHERE course_id=@courseId 
                        AND   branch_id IN(" + branchId + @") 
                        AND  (@firstYrPercent is null OR first_year_percent>=@firstYrPercent)
                        AND  (@secondYrpercent is null OR second_year_percent>=@secondYrPercent)
                        AND  (@thirdYrPercent is null OR third_year_percent>=@thirdYrPercent)
                        AND  (@finalYearpercent is null OR final_year_percent>=@finalYearpercent)
                        AND  (@currentDegeePercentage is null OR current_degree_percent>=@currentDegeePercentage)
                        AND  (@passoutYear is null OR passing_year>=@passoutYear) 
                        AND  (@currentBacklog is null OR current_backlog<=@currentBacklog)
                        AND   gender=@sex 
                        AND  (@eGap is null OR gapin_education<=@eGap)
                        AND  (@highSchoolPercentge is null OR highschool_percentage>=@highSchoolPercentge)
                        AND  (@higherSchoolPercentage is null OR ssc_percentage>=@higherSchoolPercentage)
                        AND  (@grauationPercentage is null OR graduation_percentage>=@grauationPercentage)
                        AND  (@diplomaPercentage is null OR diploma_percentage>=@diplomaPercentage)
                        AND  (@noOfAtkt is null OR number_of_ATKT<=@noOfAtkt)
                        AND  (@date is null OR DOB>=@date)";

            //string cmd = "SELECT * FROM [tbl_branch] WHERE course_id IN(" + sb + ")";

            if (dbManager.OpenConnection())
            {
                dt = dbManager.GetDataTable(cmd, paramList);
                return dt;
            }
            else
            {
                dt = null;
                return dt;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            COMMON.logger.Error("Error ON Method Getting Eligible Students:SearchStudentDAO", ex);
            dt = null;
            return dt;
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dbManager.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

And followin is code called from the above method on paage App_Code/DBManager.cs

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string strCmd, Dictionary<string, object> paramList)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, _sqlCon);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in paramList)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Error when executing Query " + strCmd, ex);
            throw;
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Now i am getting exception for those null parameter which are not provided 
"Parameterized Query '(@courseId int,@passoutYear int,@currentBacklog int,@sex int,@eG' expects parameter @finalYearpercent, which was not supplied."

please correct me where i am wrong

Comment: Sorry I just have to ask: why are you not using Linq-To-Sql?

Comment: first thing i dont know Linq-To-Sq
and when i exlored it i came to know that it is from the version 3.5
while i am using 2.0
now please let me know where i am wrong or correct me regarding the structure

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simply not adding those parameters if they're null, you need to add them, but with the "value" set to DBNull.Value.

Comment: Instead of this:

paramList.Add("@finalYearpercent", finalYearpercent);


You could do this:

paramList.Add("@finalYearpercent", finalYearpercent ?? DBNull.Value);

Comment: paramList.Add("@finalYearpercent", finalYearpercent ?? DBNull.Value)
What does it mean that if fianlYearpercent is null then the parameter will not be added or something else please elaborate this sir

Comment: i think u mean to sy that if finalyearpercent have no value then add a null to this place for value.
But the thing is the same will it remove the problem?

Comment: in that case my query will be correct ? and will it bring the correct result? it will not check for null value like 
 current_degree_percent>=@currentDegeePercentage and the value for 
is null then will it automaticall sort circuit this or it will produce wrong result

Comment: The coalesce operator, ??, will check if the left side is null, and if so it will return the value from the right side. So if finalYearPercent is null, then DBNull.Value will be added as the parameter value. DBNull.Value is recognised by ADO.NET as the null value for databases (and is different from the C# keyword "null"). So you should be able to replace your line of code as I suggested previously - if you've tried that and it still doesn't work, please post a comment here and we can try to find another solution.

Comment: giving error  
Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: and i think if i chage the type int? to int then it will take default value of integer type and it defeat the very purpose of 
paramList.Add("@finalYearpercent", finalYearpercent ?? DBNull.Value)
so what to do

Comment: ??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: That's true, it looks like you need to cast the result of the coalescing as an object.

This question has some more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545711/is-it-possible-to-coalesce-string-and-dbnull-in-c